# Which database should I use in JavaScript (AngularJS) application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pouchdb, taffydb

I want to use JavaScript database in my app to store model data, So once data is received from server I will store data in database this will minimize web service communication with server.

But I really don't know which library should I use to implement database in my JavaScript (angularJS) application.

Also I do not want to store data in local-storage/ web-storage for security concern.

Is there any JavaScript database available to store data?

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ForerunnerDB (http://www.forerunnerdb.com) to CRUD your data on the browser. It uses IndexedDB for persistence with fallback to WebSQL and then finally LocalStorage. It includes both encryption and compression for secure and efficient persistent data storage.

It integrates with AngularJS out of the box including two-way data binding to views, making it very easy to use with your existing AngularJS project.

In regards to persistent storage, I'm afraid you will not be able to efficiently store data without using one of the above mentioned persistence options.

Answer (score 0):

There are other options like WebSQL and indexedDB for storing data , but they are as insecure as localstorage . Additionally , Local storage is the most [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=local%20storage) one amongst three

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about security, PouchDB has a [crypto-pouchdb](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/crypto-pouch) plugin that will encrypt your database.